# C++ Unexpected behaviour of polymorphic cloning

Tags: c++, polymorphism, clone

I have a base class Animal and templated derived class `Specie<T>`. I would like to use polymorphic cloning to return an object of the right derived type when I have a pointer to the base class Animal. The cloning I implemented seems to always return a pointer to Animal. Not what I expected, but I do not understand why. On the other hand, if I do a dynamic_cast 'manually', it works. Any idea ?

```
#include <iostream>


class Dog;
class Cat;
class Rat;


// Base class
class Animal{

public:
  virtual Animal * clone() = 0;

};





// Derived class
template <class T1>
class Specie: public Animal{


public:

  Specie<T1> * clone();

  void DoSomething();


};



// Purpose of clone(): Return a pointer of type Specie<T1> when applied
// to a pointer to class Animal
template <class T1>
Specie<T1> * Specie<T1>::clone(){

  Specie<T1> *obj;

  obj = dynamic_cast<Specie<T1> *>(this);

  return obj;

}






// To identify a Dog
template <>
void Specie<Dog>::DoSomething(){

  std::cout << "This is a Dog..." << std::endl;

}


// To identify a Cat
template <>
void Specie<Cat>::DoSomething(){

  std::cout << "This is a Cat..." << std::endl;

}


int main(){

Specie<Dog> Dingo;
Specie<Cat> Tom;

Dingo.DoSomething();
Tom.DoSomething();


Animal *animal3;
animal3 = &Dingo;






// The following works
// Successfull conversion from pointer-to-Animal to pointer-to-Specie<Cat> with dynamic_cast without using clone()
Animal *animal4 = new Specie<Cat>;
Specie<Cat> *animal5;

// Here I can convert the pointer to Animal to a pointer to Specie<T>
// using dynamic_cast. If animal5 was not of the correct type, the compiler would return an error.
animal5 = dynamic_cast<Specie<Cat>*>(animal4);
animal5->DoSomething(); // result ok



// I want to do the same in an automated manner with clone()
// The following DOES NOT WORK with clone()
// clone() does not return a pointer to Specie<T> as expected
// but a pointer to Animal. The compiler complains.
Animal *animal6 = new Specie<Dog>;
Specie<Dog> *bobby;
bobby = animal6->clone();


return 0;
}
```

error: a value of type "Animal *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "Specie *"
  bobby = animal6->clone();

Why does it work with dynamic_cast in the main but does not using clone() ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, your `Clone` just returns `this` instead of a copy of `*this`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work without `dynamic_cast` because the *static* return type of `Animal::clone` is `Animal*`. The *dynamic* type of `animal6` is `Specie<Dog>`, but that doesn't enter in to the type which is deduced at compile-time for the return of the `clone` function.

If you really need this, the `dynamic_cast` is necessary, but this is a code smell. If you find yourself needing the absolute dynamic type of an object a lot rather than just using virtual functions, you should think about a redesign.

Comment: Thanks. I use dynamic_cast in the function clone() but it does not seem to help.

Comment: @ChristopheJ.Ortiz that doesn't change the static type of the `clone` function.